# Pair values from two maps based on same key

Tags: java, guava

Given the following two maps with values of different types but same key types

```
Map<Key, Dog> indexedDogs =  Maps.uniqueIndex(dogs, keyGeneratorForDog);
Map<Key, Cat> indexedCats=  Maps.uniqueIndex(cats, keyGeneratorForCat);
```

I would like to pair values together based on same key:

```
Map<Dog, Cat> pairs = pair(indexedDogs, indexedCats);
```

Is there implementation for `pair()` method in Guava or something that can be easily built on top of existing Guava methods?

Comment: What if 2 keys are mapped to the same Dog instance, but different Cat instances? You can't have Dog instance for both the keys as key in your new map.

Comment: So, you want to produce a map instance for each such pairs? If that's it then it should be quite easy.

Comment: `Maps.uniqueIndex` guaranties there is one Dog per Key instance (otherwise exception is thrown), and keyGeneratorForDog will guaranty there is one Key per Dog.

Comment: Why someone marked this as question off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own method, which wouldn't be that difficult. First you need to get the Set intersection of the keys in those maps. Youc an use [`Set#retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method for that.

Then iterate over the set, and add values from both map into the new map for each key, someway along the lines of:

```
public Map<Dog, Cat> pair(Map<Key, Dog> indexedDogs, Map<Key, Cat> indexedCats) {
    Set<Key> commonKey = indexedDogs.keySet();
    commonKey.retainAll(indexedCats.keySet());

    Map<Dog, Cat> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Key key: commonKey) {
        map.put(indexedDogs.get(key), indexedCats.get(key));
    }

    return map; 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `retainAll` affect indexedDogs map? You remove some keys from the keySet(). HashMap implementation for `KeySet` does  `public boolean remove(Object o) { return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null; }`

Comment: @dzieciou Yeah it will modify the map too. In that case you can rather create a copy of the keysets.